# Task.WaitAll hangs with async/await tasks

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I must be missing something obvious, like a deadlock on `SynchronizationContext`, but I do not see why it happens, and do not understand how I can avoid it...

So, the application is Azure WorkerRole (essentially, as far as I understand, usual Windows app without UI). In the application, I am trying to parallel execution of a number of tasks, and the schematic version of my code is this:

```
private async Task DoJob()
{
    await SomeIoOperation();
}


public void MethodExecutedByWorkerRoleInAnInfiniteLoop()
{
    Log("Start");
    Task.WaitAll(DoJob(), DoJob(), DoJob());
    Log("End");
}
```

My idea here is that we are operating with default `SynchronizationContext` here, so we should avoid the deadlock that we would have in similar situation in, for example, ASP.NET.

However, **sometimes** execution hangs - Start is logged, End is not for days until I restart the worker role. Naturally,there is no way DoJob could be running that long. Oddly, this does not happen immediately after the worker role starts - it may take days or weeks of normal operation until it hangs.

I could be simplifying the code too much - maybe it is important what exactly happens in `SomeIoOperation` - but I feel this is something obvious related to `SynchronizationContext` misuse.

Will `SomeIoOperation.ConfigureAwait(false)` help? I cannot even test it, because I do not know if it is working because the issue is fixed, or will eventually hang after a few more days.

Ideas?

Comment: This article will enlighten you on the cause http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Add in `Log(SynchronizationContext.Current);` and if it isn't `null` you would know you have an issue with `SynchronizationContext`.

Comment: `DoJob` will always want to synchronize to the calling context. It doesn't matter which context `SomeIoOperation` uses.

Comment: @Gusdor, I have read a number of articles by now... They clearly explain why the issue can occur in Windows UI or ASP.NET applications. From what I understood, the same is not true in my case.

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich do you know that stops the articles from applying to this case?

Comment: @Gusdor, they are about UI applications, mine is not UI. I think it matters, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich specifically, they are applications with a single threaded `SynchronizationContext` - what is the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` when you call `DoJob` ?

Comment: @Gusdor it is null - i.e, default is used, just like I thought.

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich: Can you also check `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default`? It doesn't look to me like there's anything wrong with this code; I'm wondering if it's a problem in the code not shown. Try reducing to a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @StephenCleary, `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default` - `true`. The problem with a minimal reproducible example is that I need to wait for maybe a couple of weeks for this to reproduce. I'll try to invent something here... If I suppose the problem is in the core await, I will replace it with await Task.Delay(60000) - this will definitely make the execution truly async, right? Because currently my i/o operation may be actually fast enough to execute synchronously by framework - makes sense?

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich: It shouldn't make any difference whether it completes synchronously or asynchronously. You may want to try different kinds of load tests on a separate server, and see if there's conditions where you can make it repro faster.

Answer (score 14):

You exactly fall in deadlock on SynchronizationContext.
Just use `WhenAll` instead of `WaitAll`:

```
public async Task MethodExecutedByWorkerRoleInAnInfiniteLoop()
{
    Log("Start");
    await Task.WhenAll(DoJob(), DoJob(), DoJob());
    Log("End");
}
```

and all will work.

Comment: This method is executed in a loop - the caller will want to know when the method has completed. IMO, this revision should return `Task`.

Comment: Thank you. I just forget to change void on Task.

Comment: But then in my loop I will have to do `MethodExecutedByWorkerRoleInAnInfiniteLoop().Wait()` - will not it cause deadlock there? There is no async version of `RoleEntryPoint` in `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime`, as far as I know, so I will not be able to await my `MethodExecutedByWorkerRoleInAnInfiniteLoop` anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelSagalovich If you want to use `await`, you should refactor your code to be _async all the way_.

Comment: @Gusdor, I know that, and looking into using https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext for this. Still, I'd really like to know why there are deadlocks where I think there should not be any.